# WCF: Using Secure Message with Certificate Revokation List checking

Tags: wcf, security, ssl

I have an enterprise issued certificate that I want to use to secure a WCF message channel.  The certutil program tells me that both the CRL and delta CRL are valid (status = "Verified").  I'm using the sample WCF programs from (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459); specifically the MessageSecurity.sln test.  When I replace the self-signed certificate with the Enterprise CA-generated certificate, I get the error:

***The X.509 certificate CN=localhost chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.***

Has anyone got message based channels working with anything other than self-signed certificates (i.e. with a valid CRL distribution point)?  Any ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact!  The client maintains a cache of CRLs.  After properly configuring the CRL distribution point, the cache with the erroneous CRL locations prevented the WCF sample from running.  When it magically started working two days later, I did some digging and found out that the lists are cached.  You can clear the lists manually with:

```
certutil -urlcache crl delete
```

After using this command I was able to predictably and reliably use my Enterprise CA generated cert to establish **Message** and **TransportWithMessageCredentials** channels.